# C# Getting window's title by handle in Hebrew return question marks

Tags: c#, titlebar

I am using this: to get window's title by its handle:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")] private static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder title, int size);

StringBuilder title = new StringBuilder(256);
GetWindowText(hWnd, title, 256);
```

If the title has hebrew chars, it replaces them by question marks.
I guess the problem is related to econding or something... how can I solve it?

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 8 Pro 64 bit, doesnt matter - works same in all versions (I assume, if I tested in my windows and windows xp)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder title, int size);
```

Comment: DAMN that was fast and pretty easy. Thank you! :D

Comment: I think there is an error here. The `int hWnd` should be changed to `IntPtr hWnd`

Answer (score 12):

Your question contains a little error, that might not occurs very often. You assume, that the title has a max length of 256 characters, which might be enough for most cases. But as this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135543/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-window-title-passed-to-setwindowtext?rq=1) shows, the length could be at 100K characters, maybe more. So I would use another helper function: GetWindowTextLength

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

public static string GetWindowTitle(IntPtr hWnd)
{
    var length = GetWindowTextLength(hWnd) + 1;
    var title = new StringBuilder(length);
    GetWindowText(hWnd, title, length);
    return title.ToString();
}
```

Comment: For me length always equals (real length -1). Not sure why, but simple 
`var length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd) + 1;` fixes my problem.

Comment: @alexWyler I stumbled upon the same issue but forget to update my answer. I assume GetWindowTitle returns the length without the terminator \0 that is used in C and C++ to mark the end of the string. But its only a guess