# Cyrillic CharUnion.UnicodeChar

Tags: c#, winapi, unicode, char

I've faced a problem with Cyrillic unicode chars in CharUnion structure.

Here is DLLImport declaration:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WriteConsoleOutput(
      SafeFileHandle hConsoleOutput,
      CharInfo[] lpBuffer,
      Coord dwBufferSize,
      Coord dwBufferCoord,
      ref SmallRect lpWriteRegion);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(
        string fileName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileAccess,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint fileShare,
        IntPtr securityAttributes,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int flags,
        IntPtr template);
```

Using WriteConsoleOutputW or changing CharSet just leads to Ascii chars showed wrong, but no changes with cyrilic unicode.

Here are structures:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct CharUnion
{
  [FieldOffset(0)] public char UnicodeChar;
  [FieldOffset(0)] public byte AsciiChar;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct CharInfo
{
  [FieldOffset(0)] public CharUnion Char;
  [FieldOffset(2)] public short Attributes;
}
```

Creating Handle to be used by WriteConsoleOutput:

```
SafeFileHandle Handle = CreateFile("CONOUT$", 0x40000000, 2, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

And here is an example how i fill it:

```
CharInfo[] buffer = new CharInfo[10];
buffer.Char.UnicodeChar = '\u0430';
```

After that I use imported **WriteConsoleOutput** function to write it to console buffer.
It works fine while I'm not working with cyrilic letters.

In case above i got "0" symbols in output (it's equal '\u0030', if I'm not mistaken), it seems to me that it's just read only one char's byte.

Could you please assist me with this problem?
Really can't find anything relative.

UPD:

```
Console.WriteLine('\u0430');
```

Writes character correctly. So i don't think that problem is in console encoding. Also changing it gives me no any result.

Comment: You probably didn't declare your dllimport correctly. See [C# Getting window's title by handle in Hebrew return question marks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19144658/c-sharp-getting-windows-title-by-handle-in-hebrew-return-question-marks)

Comment: @raymond-chen
Thank you for link,unfortunately i'll be able to try it only tomorrow, as soon as i'll have any result,i'll notify you
Thank you again

Comment: @raymond-chen
As I promissed:
Changing CharSet give me no any positive result. Also i've tried to use WriteConsoleOutputW, but still the same. Ascii part of console output changed to wrong symbols, but with '\u0430' i still got "0" in output. No changes here

Comment: Please share your dllimport declaration.

Comment: @raymond-chen
Updated post with dllimport declaration and creating SafeFileHandle

Comment: You didn't set the CharSet on your dllimport WriteConsoleOutput declaration. CharSet defaults to Ansi.

Comment: @raymond-chen As i said above, i've already tried to set charset for WriteConsoleOutput,but it just corrupt ascii chars ang give no any result with cyrilic unicode.
I've reverted it back due it not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that your `Console.WriteLine(buffer)` call is writing to a console configured for ASCII.

Change your console to display Unicode characters by doing `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` and then try outputting your buffer.

Comment: Please see post update, already tried at, also just writing this symbol in console using Console.WriteLine gives positive result even with default encoding.

Comment: if I do `buffer[0].Char.UnicodeChar = '\u0430';` and write to console the unicode char it seems to display fine

Comment: Same,but problem appears only if i use windows function WriteConsoleOutput

Comment: aha! I wasnt aware of that. I guess you might want to add that as another question rather than appending to the same one